# Trigger to Increment the Number value when new Lead is created when Lead Country is india

Tags: apex, trigger

My requirement is that when i create a lead with country as 'india', there is a custom field named 'India_Auto_Number__c' where it should update as 1, and again when i create a lead with country name 'india' it should increment to 2...like this it should keep on incrementing till 5th lead, when i try to insert 6th lead, it should again update as 1
how do i achieve this functionality
i went through below links but still i could not achieve the functionality
any help would be highly appriciated

[How to generate auto number using triggers](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/100097/how-to-generate-auto-number-using-triggers)

i have tried the trigger

```
    trigger LeadIncrementV2 on Lead (before insert,Before Update) {


    Lead lds = new Lead();

    Lead ld = [SELECT India_Auto_Number__c  from Lead LIMIT 1];

    integer LatestNumber = Integer.valueOf(lds.India_Auto_Number__c);

    for(Lead llds : Trigger.New){
        if(Trigger.OldMap.get(llds.id).Country == 'India'){ // i am getting an error as " Null Pointer Exception"

            llds.India_Auto_Number__c = LatestNumber + 1;
            // India_Auto_Number__c is an custom number field
        }
    }

    lds.India_Auto_Number__c= LatestNumber + 1;
    update lds;        

}
```

Comment: you're getting null pointer because in case of insert, `Trigger.oldmap` is not available.

Comment: @Rohith how do i correct it??

Comment: `if(llds.Country == 'India')` this should the issue. Also I see there are lot of issues with your code. The SOQL might not give the first record which has country India. You need to add country check in the SOQL.

Comment: I tried this code but the auto number is taking in this sequence 1,3,5,7....etc.....trigger LeadIncrementV3 on Lead (before insert, before update) {
    for(Lead l : Trigger.new){

        if (l.Country =='India'){
            l.India_Auto_Number__c = l.India_Auto_Number__c != null ? l.India_Auto_Number__c +1: 0;
        }
        
    }
}

Comment: trigger LeadIncrementV3 on Lead (before insert, before update) {
    for(Lead l : Trigger.new){

        if (l.Country =='India'){
            l.India_Auto_Number__c = l.India_Auto_Number__c != null ? l.India_Auto_Number__c +1: 0;
        }
        
    }
}

Comment: how do i increment with +1 records when i create a new lead records with Country as India

trigger LeadIncrementV3 on Lead (before insert, before update) {
    for(Lead l : Trigger.new){

        if (l.Country =='India'){
            l.India_Auto_Number__c = l.India_Auto_Number__c != null ? l.India_Auto_Number__c +1: 0;
        }
        
    }
}

Comment: Do you allow the country to be updated from india to other? If your max `India_Auto_Number__c` is now 4, and let's say Lead #3 country is changed to other, what would be the numbering rule in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of issues with your code:

1. Trigger.oldmap is not available at the time of insert.
2. SOQL query should fetch the latest `India_Auto_Number__c` from the database to
   decide what number should be assigned to new lead.

Based on above points, below are the changes I did in your code:

```
trigger LeadIncrementV2 on Lead (before insert, Before Update) {
    if (Trigger.isbefore) {
      integer LatestNumber = 1;
      List<Lead> lds = [SELECT India_Auto_Number__c  from Lead where Country = 'India' Order by India_Auto_Number__c desc LIMIT 1];
      if (lds != null && lds.size () > 0) {
        LatestNumber = Integer.valueOf (lds[0].India_Auto_Number__c);
        LatestNumber++;
      }

      for (Lead llds : Trigger.New) {
          if (llds.Country == 'India') { 
              if (LatestNumber == 5)
                LatestNumber = 1;
              llds.India_Auto_Number__c = LatestNumber;
              LatestNumber ++;
          }
      }
    }
}
```

Please note that above logic is not tested however it should give you fair amount of idea.

Comment: what about concurrency?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal Sorry I didn't get you. What exactly are you trying to say?

Comment: when 2  or more leads created at the same time, in different transactions by different users.

Comment: @PranayJaiswal good point however I'm not really sure how exactly we can avoid that. Any insights would be appreciated.

Comment: @Rohit I am getting an error in the line 6 - System.ListException: List index out of bounds: but there is a data in the list, i dont know why its throing error

Comment: @ManjunathS.C Run this query `SELECT India_Auto_Number__c  from Lead where Country = 'India' Order by India_Auto_Number__c desc LIMIT 1` in your developer console and also refer updated answer.

Comment: @Rohit i modified the code and its working fine, but when i am writing the test class for that trigger, i am getting error know as "too many soql queries 101" in the line 3 of the trigger

Comment: Since your original issue is solved request you to accept the answer. The new issue which you’re facing is altogether a different question. Request you to post a new question with all the details of your test class.